# How to run stratch in webstorm 9

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Does anyone know how to run node stratch file in webstorm.

when I click run, the node interpreter field is set to be 63301d04/scratch, and the Edit configuration error says that Error: path to Node is not correct. I tried to fix this and move the 63301d04/scratch to the javascript file but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run scratch file in WebStorm 9. Seems will be fixed soon. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13861